# Why isn't Floetrol (or the same chemical) just added to paint by the manufacturer

Tags: painting, paint

I keep hearing how adding Floetrol gives much better results when painting mouldings and doors etc. As gloss paint is almost always used for these surfaces, my question is: why does gloss not just have this substance added as standard by the paint manufacturer?

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd like to know too, and there must be a reason...  Some thoughts (could all be wrong): Reduces coverage/hide, reduces shelf life, affects drying time, increases cost or affects adhesion?

Comment: I imagine it's because different paint viscosities make sense for different situations, such as material being painted, desired thickness of coat, temperature, humidity, etc. If you need a range, it's a lot easier to start with something on the thick side and thin it out than vise versa.

Comment: I have the same question. I purchased SW Emerald at $70 a gallon and it dries (within 1-2 minute) so fast that I consider adding Floetrol. Why SW is not at least presenting Floetrol has an option?